# laravel accesing resource folder by helper method+ routing

Tags: laravel, routes, helpermethods

Edit : Solved ,as  DigitalDrifter siggested , npm run dev will automatically move all assets deom resouece to public . so dont waste time on resource folder access .

as per laravel docs ,I run command

```
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

to create auth scaffoldings . it created all assests in resource folder project
 I want to access js /css inside resource folder by helper method+ routing

[image]

app.blade.php

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

here is what i tried in routing to access js or scss file

```
Route::get('/resources/js/{filename}', function($filename){
    $path = resource_path() . '\js\{filename}';

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    return $response;
});

Route::get('/resources/css/{scss}', function($filename){
    $path = resource_path() . '\sass\{scss}';

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    return $response;
});
```

but it is not working .any thing more can be tried to access resource ??

Comment: Routes dont map to your project directories like that. Why do you need to access the raw resource rather than what's in the public directory?

Comment: i run  php artisan ui vue --auth to create auth scaffoldings . it created all assests in resource folder . just wanted to tht should i move all assets from resource to public

Comment: Ah, you need to run `npm run dev` to compile the resources and output them to the public folder.

Comment: i think you solved my problem , i am testing then will reply

Comment: 'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command, this err comes on npm run dev

Comment: Run `npm install cross-env --dev` to resolve that.

Comment: ok , did that , after also did php artisan config:cache . still i run php artisan serve . issue comes  "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". any clue ?

Comment: Do the files `public/js/app.js` and `public/css/app.css` now exist in your project after running `npm run dev`?

Comment: ok , resolved , need to restart every thing , thanks